# OpenSSL certificate creation and pem/cer output

Tags: curl, https, private-key, public-key, php-openssl

There are a few similar question here, but none of them answered my case. I am attempting to get an SSL certificate to work in CURL over HTTPS for a web service.

First, I created the csr

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myserver_private.key -out myserver_pkcs10.csr
```

I have both of these files on my linux box.

I sent the csr file to be signed by the web service and they sent back:

`signingauthority_Root_CA.crt`, `myserver_pkcs10.csr`, `theirserver_CA.crt`

For my `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "?.pem");` I now need the .pem file. How do I create this and from which file? `theirserver_CA.crt`?

Do I also need to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "?.cer");` and if so, how do I create this .cer file? Is this the intermediary aka signing authority?

Answer (score 1):

Open the `*.crt` files with a text editor. If they are PEM, they wil contain blocks of Base64 text delimited with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`.

If that's the case, simply rename the file.

If the file is a binary file it is DER.  To convert to Base64 (PEM) use:

```
openssl x509 -in <DER filename> -outform PEM -out <PEM filename>
```

The `CURLOPT_CAINFO` will be `theirserver_CA.crt`

I'd have thought the CA would have sent back `myserver.crt` too, which would be used for `CURLOPT_SSLCERT`.

Use:

```
openssl x509 -noout -subject -issuer -in <PEM file>
```

to view the subject and issuer of each certificate in order to work out what you've been sent.

Comment: This is correct. I figured it out before you answered, but good to know it was basically correct. I converted each file to DER, then to PEM (maybe it wasn't totally necessary this way). Then I added the contents of `myserver_private.key` to `myserver_pkcs10.pem`, before `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and renamed the file to `myserver_full.pem`. When I tried `myserver_pkcs10.pem` (without the private key) in `CURLOPT_SSLCERT` it threw an error, so I figured I needed to also add the private key.